# File object not being modified by function

Tags: java, swing, file, reference

I want the following code to ask the user for a file and (if it exists) store it in curFile. This shouldn't be a problem since curFile is passed by reference. If the process is successful, it should return true, otherwise it should return false.

```
void foo() {
    File curFile = null;

    // Open a file and set curFile to this file
    openFile(curFile);
}

bool openFile(File file) {
    // Ask the user for the file to open
    File tempFile = getFileFromUserInput()
    // If the file exists, set file and (thus curFile) to tempFile and return true
    if (tempFile.exists()) {
        file = tempFile;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the code doesn't set `curFile = tempFile`. I think the reason for this is that although curFile is an object and is passed by reference, I'm not modifying this object in the function. I'm putting a new object in the variable. But I'm still not sure if this is the reason why it's not working. (`getFileFromUserInput()` is actually a Swing method `FileChooser.getSelectedFile()`, in case that's relevant.)

One fix is to return the file object instead of a boolean. But that would cause curFile to be written over by the return value even when it shouldn't, such as when the file doesn't exist. There are some fixes for this, like returning null if it's an invalid file and saving the old file in a temporary variable in case null is returned, but that's ugly.

The other method is to return both the boolean and File wrapped in an object, but that's even uglier.

So am I stuck with method one, or is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: *`getFileFromUserInput()`*  I hope that method is popping a `JFileChooser`.

Comment: What do you mean popping? In the real code, a static final instance of JFileChooser is being used.

Comment: *"What do you mean popping?"*  Sorry, I just meant 'opening', and I am glad your question did not mean you were showing an input dialog with a text-field to 'type the name of a file'.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no pass by reference (the c++ equivalent of `&`) in Java.  All argument passing is done by value.  Assigning to a parameter variable will not change the argument at the callsite.  Just assign the instance variable inside of openFile.  I think you want something like this.

```
File curFile = null;
bool openFile() {
    File tempFile = getFileFromUserInput();
    if (tempFile.exists()) {
        curFile = tempFile;
        return true;
    } else {
        curFile = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note the lack of an argument to `openFile`.

Comment: I don't think that's true. All object references are passed by value. This isn't equivalent of passing by reference, but it does mean that  if you modify a property of the argument object, it will modify the original object. In this case however, I've clearly stated that I'm not modifying a property, which is what I think is causing the problem. Secondly, I didn't type my example right. curFile doesn't have global scope. I'll update that right now.

Comment: But all primitives are also passed by value, so it's fair to say that Java only has pass by value as a calling semantic. I hate that term because it means different things to different people depending on their background and language of choice.

Comment: Looking at your updated code (`curFile` a local variable in some other scope), you're stuck with your other two options.  Personally, I'd pick returning `File` and using `null` to mean no file.  Of course, then your `openFile` and `getFileFromUserInput` are identical.

Comment: Then your whole code reduces to `void foo() { File curFile = getFileFromUserInput(); }`, where `curFile` might be null.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: If that's the only solution I'll go with it. I'll have to store curFile's old file in a variable and then replace curFile's value if it's null. I wanted openFile to take care of any invalid filenames, but there's also more going on in that function.